Selenium Python - как обратится к нужному элементу по индексу?
В коде html находится 4 одинаковых строчки:
<a data-name="add" class="acf-button button" href="#">Добавить изображение</a>
<a data-name="add" class="acf-button button" href="#">Добавить изображение</a>
<a data-name="add" class="acf-button button" href="#">Добавить изображение</a>
<a data-name="add" class="acf-button button" href="#">Добавить изображение</a>

Требуется кликнуть на третью ссылку.
В питоне обращаюсь к элементу таким кодом:
browser.find_element("link text", 'Добавить изображение').click()

Как мне указать что нужно кликнуть на третью ссылку?
Пробовал сделать так, но это не срабатывает, выдает ошибку:
browser.find_element("link text", 'Добавить изображение')[2].click()


find_element --> find_elements browser.find_elements("link text", 'Добавить изображение')[2].click()
